# For loops: How could I repeat several steps?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am relatively new to R and am a little bit confused about for loops.

I tried to repeat several steps within a for loop after a specified condition is hit. I tried to put the loop one step back, but have recognized that the loop keeps counting up and ignores my command. Here is a simple example to illustrate what I meant:

```
a <- 1:10
b <- rep(NA, 15)

fun <- function(){
  i <- 1
  for(i in 1:10){
  b[i] <- a[i]
  i <- i - 1 # This is the line I am talking about.
  }
  return(b)
}
fun()

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA NA NA NA NA
```

I have expected that this code would run forever and assigns only 1's. Is there a way how I could move one step back within for loops or would I have to do a completely different approach?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to write a sorting algorithm and need to repeat the complete loop, if one number is smaller like the first number of my vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way a for loop works is that if you have `for (i in 1:10)`, first `i` is set to 1, and the body of the loop is executed. Then we go back to the top and `i` is set to 2, and the body of the loop is executed again. Basically, this loop:

```
for (x in 1:3) {
    print(x^2)
}
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
x = 1
print(x^2)
x = 2
print(x^2)
x = 3
print(x^2)
```

So your attempt to roll the loop back a step by changing `i` doesn't work because the `for` loop doesn't actually monitor what `i` is, it just runs the body of the loop once for each element of the original `1:10` sequence.

If you want to sometimes repeat a step, you should use a `while` loop and increment `i` manually:

```
a <- 1:10
b <- rep(NA, 15)

i <- 1
while (i <= 10) {
    b[i] <- a[i]
    # Flip a coin, don't move on if it comes up tails
    # Replace this test with the relevant condition you
    #   want to check for
    if (sample(c(0, 1), 1) == 1) {
       i <- i + 1 
    } else {
        print(paste("Repeating with i =", i))
    }
}
```